# Represent a sparse matrix in C using the CSparse Library

Tags: c, matrix, linear-algebra, sparse-matrix

I can't understand how can easily represent a sparse matrix in C using the CSparese Library.

That's what I want

```
    | 6.0 0.0 2.0 |
A = | 3.0 8.0 0.0 |
    | 6.0 0.0 1.0 |
with

    | 40.0 |
b = | 50.0 |
    | 30.0 |
```

The cs Struct of the csparse  is this

```
typedef struct cs_sparse    /* matrix in compressed-column or triplet form */
{
    csi nzmax ;     /* maximum number of entries */
    csi m ;         /* number of rows */
    csi n ;         /* number of columns */
    csi *p ;        /* column pointers (size n+1) or col indices (size nzmax) */
    csi *i ;        /* row indices, size nzmax */
    double *x ;     /* numerical values, size nzmax */
    csi nz ;        /* # of entries in triplet matrix, -1 for compressed-col */
} cs ;
```

That's what I do

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    cs A;
    int  N = 3;
    double b[]={1,2,3};
    double data[]={1,1,1};
    csi columnIndices[]={0,1,2};
    csi rowIndices[]={0,1,2};
    A.nzmax =3;
    A.m = N;
    A.n = N;
    A.p = &columnIndices[0];
    A.i = &rowIndices[0];
    A.x = &data[0];
    A.nz = 3;

    cs *B = cs_compress(&A);
    int status =  cs_cholsol(0,B,&b[0]);



    printf("status=%d",status);   // status always returns 0, which means error
    return 0;
```

What I ask, is how can I populate my matrix with my data and which method I must use to solve it.

Thanks

Comment: How big are your matrices in practice?

Comment: Big matrix for example 918*918
My code posted is only to understand how can I work with this library... but I need to work with bigger matrices

Answer (score 2):

You can either use `cs_load` which read a matrix from a file. (one entry per line, `LINE COLUMN DOUBLE`, you can see this [example](http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/st/kershaw.st))

Or use `cs_entry` to set a value of the matrix : `cs_entry (matrix, i, j, 0.42);`

You might want to see this [full example](http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/c_src/csparse/csparse_demo1.c), and [this](https://www.cise.ufl.edu/research/sparse/CSparse/)

### Update

The data structure `A` should not contain any information about `b`. The whole data structure is a sparse representation of `A`. Moreover, you should not initialize it yourself, but let `cs_spalloc` do the work. (by example `cs_spalloc (0, 0, 1, 1, 1)`).
And then use cs_entry to set the values.

For the right-hand part of the equation you want to solve (`Ax = b`), then if `b` is supposed to be dense, the you should use a simple C array :

Simply : `double b[]={10.0,20.0,30.0};`

Finally you can call `cs_lsolve(A, b)`.

Comment: wow so nice! But how can I set the coefficient? the method to solve is the cs_lsolve?

Comment: About the solving part, your question is not so clear, but I guess you want to solve something like `Ax = b`. You can use `cs_usolve(A, x)`. The vector `b` is given with the pointer `x`, and the output is given by `x`. (x is dense)

Comment: That's what I do to try,     cs_entry (&A, 0, 0, 1.0);
    cs_entry (&A, 0, 1, 0.0);
    cs_entry (&A, 0, 2, 2.0);
    cs_entry (&A, 1, 0, 3.0);
    cs_entry (&A, 1, 1, 4.0);
    cs_entry (&A, 1, 2, 0.0);
    cs_entry (&A, 2, 0, 0.0);
    cs_entry (&A, 2, 1, 0.0);
    cs_entry (&A, 2, 2, 5.0);

Comment: Your wondering how to create the `b` vector ? It is a simple C array. Or you want `b` to be also sparse ?

Comment: I need to solve the problem in the example to understand how csparse works. I've posted an update in my question with my actually code. It doesn't work. But I can't understand what's wrong.

Comment: mmm my code always return 0! That's something that I cannot understand... I've update my code for the 2nd time! take a look when you have time! thanks

Comment: I need to solve a large sparse matrix (1000x1000)... so I can't use the gauss elimination! thanks