# Storing high dimensional data to calculate dense units in subspace clustering algorithms like clique,enclus,etc. ?

Tags: c, cluster-analysis, clique

How to store high dimensional data to calculate dense units in subspace clustering algorithms like clique,enclus,etc. ? For example , I have 20 dimensions of a point , so if array is used , I have to allocate 20 dimensions to it, which will run out of memory. The code is to be written in 'C',so please suggest what can I use to store the high dimensional points .

Comment: If you have an N points with 20 dimensions and N*20*sizeof(dimension) is not fitting in the memory, you need more memory.

Comment: N*20*sizeof(dimension) will fit in the memory(it is given), but in clustering algorithms like clique ,the each dimensions are divided into 'm' equal intervals . so if there are 'k' dimensions then the grid size will be 'm^k'. But this grid of 'm^k' will contain only N points , so it is possible that most of the grid cell will be empty.

Comment: Would a sparse matrix solve your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22907166/represent-a-sparse-matrix-in-c-using-the-csparse-library

Answer (score 0):

Some algorothms like CLIQUE just don't work for high-dimensional data.

You will have to **rethink the algorithm** not try to find a technical hack to make it somehow work.

Comment: Clique is used for high dimensional data. You read it here http://www.cs.cornell.edu/johannes/papers/1998/sigmod1998-clique.pdf

Comment: No, it is not. It's running time is exponential in the dimensionality, which means it will only work for low to medium dimensionalities. It is okay if you want to find 5 dimensional clusters in a 20 dimensional data set, but it will die on finding something in 1000+ dimensions.

Comment: In the question I have mentioned '20' dimensions as example & not 1000. But 20 dimension is also too much for array to store because if I divide each dimension into 10 parts then array will require '10^20' which will give the error of out-of-memory. Can u suggest some method/data structure which can be used in place of array.

Comment: Only store the non-empty cells. You probably don't have 10^20 points.